# Understanding flex-shrink when the value is less than 1

Tags: css, flexbox

Let's say I have a flex container with only two children, and I want to allow them to shrink, so I give both a non-zero `flex-shrink` value. As I understand it, what matters is the ratio between the values. So, setting the values as:

- first child 4, second child 1
- first child 100, second child 25
- first child 1, second child 0.25

should all yield the same behavior. And it does... until one of the children hits its `min-width`. In the third case, the second child overflows out of the container. I would say this is a bug, but it's consistent across Chrome, Safari and Firefox.

Here's a [playground](https://codesandbox.io/s/css-flex-shrink-weird-gxyzcj?file=/index.html), and here's a screenshot showing "the bug", where I have added the measure of each child. Each child `width` property is set to 200px and `min-width` to 100px. The container's width is 300px in the first case, and 220px in the second case.

```css
body {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

.container {
  border: deeppink 2px solid;
  display: flex;
  height: 50px;
}

.box {
  width: 200px;
  min-width: 100px;
}

.green {
  background: green;
}

.blue {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<h2>First case, both boxes have pixels to give up</h2>
<h3>Flex shrink 4 and 1</h3>
<div class="container" style="width: 300px;">
  <div class="green box" style="flex-shrink: 4;"></div>
  <div class="blue box" style="flex-shrink: 1;"></div>
</div>
<h3>Flex shrink 100 and 25</h3>
<div class="container" style="width: 300px;">
  <div class="green box" style="flex-shrink: 100;"></div>
  <div class="blue box" style="flex-shrink: 25;"></div>
</div>
<h3>Flex shrink 1 and 0.25</h3>
<div class="container" style="width: 300px;">
  <div class="green box" style="flex-shrink: 1;"></div>
  <div class="blue box" style="flex-shrink: 0.25;"></div>
</div>

<h2>Second case, first box is at its minimun</h2>
<h3>Flex shrink 4 and 1</h3>
<div class="container" style="width: 220px;">
  <div class="green box" style="flex-shrink: 4;"></div>
  <div class="blue box" style="flex-shrink: 1;"></div>
</div>
<h3>Flex shrink 100 and 25</h3>
<div class="container" style="width: 220px;">
  <div class="green box" style="flex-shrink: 100;"></div>
  <div class="blue box" style="flex-shrink: 25;"></div>
</div>
<h3>Flex shrink 1 and 0.25: overflow!</h3>
<div class="container" style="width: 220px;">
  <div class="green box" style="flex-shrink: 1;"></div>
  <div class="blue box" style="flex-shrink: 0.25;"></div>
</div>
```

Can anyone explain what's going on?

[image]

Comment: Thanks @MichaelBenjamin! I read that reference, but that doesn't make any distinction between flex-shrink values greater or smaller than 1 

Comment: @MichaelBenjamin I remember something similar with values less than 1 .. now I need to find it

Comment: @TemaniAfif, I've read about values less than one with `flex-grow` ([see here](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#valdef-flex-flex-grow)), but hadn't seen anything in the spec about `flex-shrink`.

Comment: @MichaelBenjamin it's basically the same logic. Later in the spec they talk about flex factor and it's either flex-shrink or flex-grow and both have the same logic when the sum is less than 1. The answer below should be good now. After a few comments we got it 100% accurate (I hope so)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will try to summarize what it's happening using easy words because the words of the Spec are nightmare.

What you face is related to two things. The first one is "Fix min/max violations." and the second one is having a sum of `flex-shrink` factor less than 1. Everything is detailed in this part: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#resolve-flexible-lengths

Here is what is happening step-by-step.

First, we start by finding the size of our elements to notice we have an overflow and a negative free space. `200px + 200px > 220px` and the free space is `180px`.

We calculate the "scaled flex shrink factor" of each item then we get the ratio to have  `0.8 = (1 * 200)/(1 * 200 + .25*200)` and `0.2 = (.25 * 200)/(1 * 200 + .25*200)`

The first item will shrink by `.8*180px = 144px` and the second one by `.2*180px = 36px` which will give us the new width equal to `56px` and `164px`

After this we will hit the "Fix min/max violations" because the first item is smaller than its `min-width` (the second one is fine). So we clamp it to `100px` and we **freze** it. All the trick is here, we no more touch the first item and we run the algorithm again considering only the second item.

So our new configuration is an element with `200px` width and a shrink factor equal to `0.25` inside a space equal to `220px - 100px = 120px`. And here strike the second thing where the sum of the shrink factors (we only have one) is less than 1 so our item will not shrink all the negative free space.

The negative free space is equal to `200px - 120px = 80px` but it's not the one we will consider because if we follow the Spec we can read:

> Calculate the remaining free space as for initial free space, above. **If the sum of the unfrozen flex items’ flex factors is less than one**, multiply the initial free space by this sum. If the magnitude of this value **is less than** the magnitude of the remaining free space, use this as the remaining free space.

The initial free space was `180px` so we multiple this value by `.25` to get `45px`. The magnitude of this value is smaller than the new free space (the remaining free space equal to `80px`) so we use it.

Now you know the end of the story. We have one item that needs to shrink by `45px` and not `80px` so its final width is `155px` and we have an overflow (`155px + 100px > 220px`)

The logic behind such behavior is to have a kind of continuous function between `0` and `1`. `0` means no shrinking and `1` means full shrinking and more than `1` is still full shrinking but in between we have a partial shrinking.

Here is a simplified example to understand.

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

.container {
  border: deeppink 2px solid;
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.box {
  width: 300px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box" style="flex-shrink: 0;"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="box" style="flex-shrink: 0.2;"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="box" style="flex-shrink: 0.4;"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="box" style="flex-shrink: 0.6;"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="box" style="flex-shrink: 0.8;"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="box" style="flex-shrink: 1;"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="box" style="flex-shrink: 10;"></div>
</div>
```

As you can see, the item slowing shrink when we increase the value from `0` until we reach `1`.

You will not have any overflow issue with the other cases because, even after freezing some items, you will have the sum of shrink factor equal or greater than `1` so we will always use the new calculated free space

Comment: I consider this answer as a Draft for now. I will update it when I find the missing part detailing the part where the sum is less than 1

Comment: thanks @TemaniAfif ! I have wanted to understand this for a long time. If I'm reading the docs link correctly, l think you're making a mistake in this step:

"So our new configuration is an element with 164px width and a shrink factor equal to 0.25 inside a space equal to 220px - 100px = 120px".

I believe we need to start over, not with 164px. In step 4b, we have 220px - 100px - 200px = -180px initial free space. Now, since "the sum of the unfrozen flex items’ flex factors is less than one" (0.25), we multiply 180px * 0.25 = 45px. So, we end up with 200px - 45px = 155px.  Makes sense?

Comment: @LGenzelis but `220px - 100px - 200px` is equal to `-80px`

Comment: Damn! xD Let's go at it again. We have initial free space = 220px - 200px - 200px = -180px (this is not part of the loop, it doesn't get recalculated). First iteration of the loop is as you described. For second iteration, 4b, we have remaining free space = -180px * 0.25 = -55px. In 4c, all those -55px go to our only unfrozen item.

Comment: @LGenzelis yes the calculation stand but still the remaining free space is calculated again "Calculate the remaining free space as for initial free space," but it seems the trick is within the " If the magnitude of this value is less than the magnitude of the remaining free space, use this as the remaining free space." ... so we have a new remaining space (80px) that is bigger than the 55px value so we use the 55px. This should also explain the "sum of less than 1" I was looking for

Comment: Exactly! Only one thing, I screw up math again (I have to stop doing these in my head, I'm sorry ), and it's 45px, not 55px as in my last comment. But I believe you're correct, we have to candidate values: the -80px and the -45px, and we use -45px because we have to pick the value with the smallest magnitude. Let me know when you've updated your answer so that I can accept it :)

Comment: @LGenzelis answer update but you can wait before accepting, maybe someone else will have somethng to add ;)